# Relation between electric and magnetic fields in EM waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

For a plane electromagnetic wave, propagating in vacuum space, it's easy to prove that

$$\vec E=\vec B \times \vec c.$$

Does this relation holds for other types of waves other than plane waves?